# getPressure and getSize always return the same value

Tags: android, touch

Does anyone have any idea why getPressure() returns always 0.4 and getSize() returns 0.12...?

Code snippet:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    System.out.println(event.getPressure());
    System.out.println(event.getSize())
    return true;

}
```

I think getPressure might not work, because there is no any physical functionality. But I can't figure out why getSize doesn't work?

Comment: What device?  How are you testing?

Comment: ASUS TF300TG. I touch to the screen with different strength.

Answer (score 1):

TF300TG is android4.0, in Settings->Developer Options, check the "**Pointer Location**".

Comment: Thanks! Very useful answer. Just to elaborate a bit - if you enable 'pointer location', your phone adds a constant overlay to your screen that shows all the main pointer data including size and pressure. By enabling this I could quickly see that my phone (moto) doesn't ever change size (0) or pressure (1) whatever motions I do, which saved me time trying to figure out if my code was wrong. Thanks! (I guess some phones just don't report values at all or don't change them)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that these are the values generated at the very first part of the motion event only?
Try outputting the values on touch MOVE, as this is where the shape normally changes. This should give you some variation.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

switch(event.getAction())
{
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
   System.out.println(event.getPressure());
   System.out.println(event.getSize());
   break;
}

return true;
```

}